# Sharing php sessions across domains

Tags: php, session

I am creating an e-commerce platform and will allow hosting of e-commerce pages using CNAME records for store domain and an ssl certificate page on another domain for the sector checkout page. Both the domains below will reside on my server pointing to same code base.

Here is an example:
http://store.mystore.com

https://checkout.phpppointofsale.com/checkout?domain=store.mystore.com

Is the only real way to not using session data for checkout process and pull from a database instead? Or use database driven sessions and look up the data that way?

Comment: If they are on the same server then perhaps you could store their sessions in a common location. Save the user's session id in a central database, associated with the user id perhaps. If no session is set, get the session id from the database and initialize the correct session. If there is none in the database, generate a new one. You would have to test it, it's just an idea. I imagine you would have to deal with concurrent access to the sessions and write your own session expiry routine which also clears the session id from the database when necessary.

Comment: comment AND answer, @ColSouth ?

Comment: I deleted the answer and write it in a comment instead